errorjava.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.4.1/
When I access with browser on ip 192.168.4.1, the esp32 accepts the connection and everything works perfectly. But due to the Java application made in Android Studio, it gives me this error:
errorjava.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.4.1/...
the code:
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://192.168.4.1/")
                        .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
                        .build();

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"error" + e);
                    }

                    @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()){
                            ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                            String body = responseBody.string();
                            Log.d(TAG,"onresponse" + body);
                        }
                    }
                });

on esp32 I am using this code
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("Server started");
}


void chamaFuncaoWifi() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  String currentLine = "";
  verificaFuncao = 0;
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    if (c == '\n') {

    } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
      currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
    }
    if (currentLine.endsWith("%7D HTTP/1.1")) {
      Serial.println("Recebido");
      currentLine.replace("%7B", "{");
      currentLine.replace("%22", "\"");
      currentLine.replace("%7D", "}");
      currentLine.replace("GET /", "");
      currentLine.replace(" HTTP/1.1", "");
      Serial.println(currentLine);
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(docRecebe, currentLine);
      if (error) {
        Serial.print("deserializeJson() failed: ");
        Serial.println(error.c_str());
        return;
      }
      verificaFuncao = docRecebe["func"];
      Serial.println(verificaFuncao);
      if (verificaFuncao == 0) {
        client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        client.println("Content-type:text/html");
        client.println();
        client.print("{\"error\":\"Post Invalido\"}");
        client.println();
      }
      if (verificaFuncao == 1) {
        Serial.println("Recebido Funcao 01");
        client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        client.println("Content-type:text/html");
        client.println();
        client.print("{\"resp\":\"1\"}");
        client.println();
      }
    }
  }
}

I would like someone to help me solve this problem, I've been trying to solve it for hours and so far I haven't been able to get it out.
EDIT: I managed to make an adaptation that works. I noticed that sometimes it gave an error and sometimes it worked, so I created a timer for it to ping and when it sends it I stop pinging. Of course I would like to understand why this is happening.
this is the log:
2024-04-07 19:39:23.570 31515-31765 ContentValues           com.example.borntorun                D  errorXjava.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.4.1/...
2024-04-07 19:39:24.013 31515-31766 TrafficStats            com.example.borntorun                D  tagSocket(6) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-04-07 19:39:24.037 31515-31766 ContentValues           com.example.borntorun                D  errorXjava.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.4.1/...
2024-04-07 19:39:24.512 31515-31767 TrafficStats            com.example.borntorun                D  tagSocket(6) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-04-07 19:39:24.590 31515-31767 ContentValues           com.example.borntorun                D  onresponseX{"resp":"1"}
            verificaPost = 1;
        int delay = 50;   // delay de 5 seg.
        int interval = 500;  // intervalo de 1 seg.
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if(verificaPost == 0) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }else{
                    enviaWifi();
                    verificaPost = 1;
                }
            }
        }, delay, interval);

   public void enviaWifi() {
    Log.d(TAG, "chamei---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    if (verificaPost == 1) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.4.1/{\"func\":\"2\"}")
                .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "errorX" + e);
                return;

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                    String body = responseBody.string();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onresponseX" + body);
                    verificaPost = 0;

                }
            }

        });
    }
}


Is there a reason why you don't use a real HTTP client? Manually creating HTTp requests and parsing the response is possible however if the server changes just a bit your client may fail. Common HTTP clients are better prepared for such situations. Also you don't have to know every but if the HTTP spec...

Your use of available()is invalid, as are most others.

@Robert I managed to make an adaptation and I'll put it in the edit
